# What should be returned from useEffect hook when the body function does a condition check?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using the useEffect hook, and in some cases I do not need to return anything. What is the best way to handle this situation?

```
// fooRef is a reference to a textfield (belonging to the same component). Sometimes the fooRef is not there,because of redirections) that's why I need to check if it exists

useEffect(() => fooRef.current && fooRef.current.focus()  , [fooRef])
```

When using it like this, React complains with the following error message:
*An effect function must not return anything besides a function, which is used for clean-up. You returned null. If your effect does not require clean up, return undefined (or nothing).*

Would the best option be to return undefined or an empty function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you intended to write

```
useEffect(() => {if (fooRef.current) fooRef.current.focus()  } , [fooRef])
```

Your current implementation is returning the the boolean result of executing `fooRef.current && fooRef.current.focus()` rather than just executing the focus function if `fooRef.current` is true.

Comment: thank you for your input. It seems that what I was missing was the curly brackets. As you have mentioned the function was directly returning the boolean result.
This also works:
useEffect(() => { fooRef.current && fooRef.current.focus()  } , [fooRef])

It's a dirty(bad) way of mimicking an if statement since fooRef will focus only if foo.current is true (defined).

Answer (score 6):

You can use `void`:

```
useEffect(() => void rooRef.current && fooRef.current.focus(), [fooRef])
```

See Kent C. Dodds video about it: [Using `void` to make arrow functions return nothing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OCTFOsCvcNs)

Answer (score 0):

When you write above syntax in arrow function, you are explicitly informing to return fooRef.current.focus(), so do something like below

```
useEffect(() => { if(fooRef.current) fooRef.current.focus() } , [fooRef])
```